# Travelling Salesman (TSP) Performance

Tags: algorithm

Can anybody tell me, how can I compare TSP Optimal and heuristics? I have implemented TSP but don't know how can I compare them. Infact, how can I find the optimal cost of the TSP? Any method or guess?

Thanks

Comment: @GregHewgill: I have given matrix as input to the TSP program and obviously it does short cutting whereas matrix doesn't contain any short cutting distances and there is no optimal cost algorithm I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Check the optimal solution with well-known benchmark instances:

Download the data from TSPLIB [here](http://www2.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/tsp/) and compare your solutions with the optimal values [here](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/STSP.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solving the TSP to optimality is an NP-hard problem.

To assess the quality of a heuristic solution, you have several options:

1. Compare it to heuristic solutions produced by other algorithms. This will give you an idea of which heuristics work better on the given instance, but obviously won't tell you anything about how close you are to the optimal solution.
2. Compare to the optimal solution. [`Concorde`](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/concorde.html) is probably your best bet for computing this.
3. Compute a lower bound for the TSP instance, and compare the heuristic solution to that. The two standard approaches are the Held-Karp lower bound and the assignment problem relaxation.
4. Use instances with known optimal solutions, such as those in [TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/).